# XUpload can't save to the model

Tags: yii, model, yii-xupload

hi i am using XUpload to upload photos in my app, however while it uploads to the respective folders, it cant save to my database. below is the code for adding the photos. the model is Carousel. please help. Thanks.

```
public function afterSave() 
{
$this->addImages();
parent::afterSave();
}

public function addImages() 
{
//If we have pending images
if( Yii::app( )->user->hasState('carouselphoto') ) {
    $userImages = Yii::app( )->user->getState('carouselphoto');
    //Resolve the final path for our images
    $path = Yii::app( )->getBasePath( )."/../images/uploads/{$this->id}/";
    //Create the folder and give permissions if it doesnt exists
    if( !is_dir( $path ) ) {
        mkdir( $path );
        chmod( $path, 0777 );
    }

    //Now lets create the corresponding models and move the files
    foreach( $userImages as $image ) {
        if( is_file( $image["path"] ) ) {
            if( rename( $image["path"], $path.$image["filename"] ) ) {
                chmod( $path.$image["filename"], 0777 );
                $img = new Carousel();
                $img->size = $image["size"];
                $img->mime = $image["mime"];
                $img->name = $image["name"];
                $img->photo_name = "/images/uploads/{$this->id}/".$image["filename"];
                $img->id = $this->id;
                if( !$img->save( ) ) {
                    //Its always good to log something
                    Yii::log( "Could not save Image:\n".CVarDumper::dumpAsString( 
                        $img->getErrors( ) ), CLogger::LEVEL_ERROR );
                    //this exception will rollback the transaction
                    throw new Exception( 'Could not save Image');
                }
            }
        } else {
            //You can also throw an execption here to rollback the transaction
            Yii::log( $image["path"]." is not a file", CLogger::LEVEL_WARNING );
        }
    }
    //Clear the user's session
    Yii::app( )->user->setState( 'carouselphoto', null );
}
}
```

thanks joe miller. here is my access rules code snippet. However, no errors whatsoever

```
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('photo_name', 'required'),
        array('gallery_id', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        array('photo_name, alt', 'length', 'max'=>256),
        // The following rule is used by search().
        // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
        array('id, photo_name, gallery_id, alt', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        array('photo_name', 'file', 'types' => 'jpg,jpeg,gif,png'),
    );
}
```

here is where it is set (actionUpload)

```
//Now we need to save this path to the user's session
            if( Yii::app( )->user->hasState('carouselphoto') ) {
                $userImages = Yii::app()->user->getState('carouselphoto');
            } else {
                $userImages = array();
            }
             $userImages[] = array(
                "path" => $path.$filename,
                //the same file or a thumb version that you generated
                //"thumb" => $path.$filename,
                "filename" => $filename,
                'size' => $model->size,
                'mime' => $model->mime_type,
                'name' => $model->name,
            );
            Yii::app( )->user->setState( 'carouselphoto', $userImages );
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! Can you add you model validation rules? Also, do you get any errors generated? Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Just a thought, but is the code above from your model Carousel? If so, you have recursion on the afterSave() method; it will be called again on the line if( !$img->save( ) ). I'm not sure what the affect will be but it can't be good!

Comment: Can you also show your Upload action in the controller? It is where the `setState('carouselphoto')` is.

Comment: The only way I can see to solve this is to use a debugger in your IDE. You need to step through the commands to the line after if( !$img->save( ) ), then inspect the $img properties. It should have a property 'errors', that will give you more information about why the model is not saving. If you can post the output here, that will be a big help.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, there's one thing you should not do is to call if( !$img->save( ) ) how @Joe Miller said you have a recursion.

I tried to print  $img->name = $image['name'] after assigned and its does work.

But that change is not reflected on database field .. dunno why.

I was going to try this way:

```
if(Yii::app()->user->hasState('xuploadFiles' )) {   
$this->addImages();
return true;
}parent::afterSave();
```

cuz probably return parent::afterSave(); always return false so it doesnt save the field.
I dunno .. I need to check it first.

### Solved

for me work this way: $this->saveAttributes(array('image_url'));

you should try if it works for you.
$this->saveAttributes(array('size,mime, name, photo_name, id '));

Comment: and where should i add that? in the controller or model?

Comment: delete all this if( !$img->save( ) ) {} and use this $this->saveAttributes(array('size,mime, name, photo_name, id '));

Comment: i did and still no change. it is not saving to the database